Result Object object when i using VAutocomplete from Vuetify
I'm using vuetify in my project and I have an object object error on all dropdown entries, the bug only occurs when there is nothing selected in the dropdown and it should come with a select placeholder please... the values on the api from the backend are sent and displayed correctly in the dropdown.
<script setup lang="ts">
import isRoutable from '@/helpers/is-routable'
import resourcesStore from '@/stores/resource-selector-store'
import useProcessModel from '@/composables/use-process-model'
import { mdiRefresh } from '@mdi/js'

type VAutocompleteProps = App.Components.Helpers.Props<'VAutocomplete'>

interface ResourceSelectorProps extends /** @vue-ignore */ VAutocompleteProps {
    table: App.Fields.TableName
    url: string
    optionsValue?: VAutocompleteProps['itemValue']
    optionsLabel?: VAutocompleteProps['itemTitle']
    customRouteGroup?: App.Routes.RouteGroup
    fetchModel?: boolean
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<ResourceSelectorProps>(), {
    optionsValue: 'id',
    optionsLabel: 'name',
    customRouteGroup: undefined,
    fetchModel: true,
})

interface ResourceSelectorEmits {
    (e: 'fetchModel', value: (typeof props)['modelValue']): void
}

const emits = defineEmits<ResourceSelectorEmits>()

const slots = defineSlots<App.Components.Helpers.Slots<'VAutocomplete'>>()

const model = defineModel<Record<string, unknown>>({ required: true })

const items = ref<(typeof props)['modelValue'][]>([])

const loading = ref(true)

async function getOptions() {
    try {
        return await csrfKy.get(props.url).json<(typeof props)['modelValue'][]>()
    } catch (error) {
        useNotificationStore().create({
            color: 'red',
            title: 'Eroare',
            text: String(error),
        })
    }
}

async function fetchOptions(eager = false) {
    loading.value = true

    if (resourcesStore.value[props.url] === undefined || eager) {
        const data = await getOptions()

        if (data) {
            resourcesStore.value[props.url] = items.value = data
        }
    } else {
        const stored = resourcesStore.value[props.url]

        if (stored) {
            items.value = stored
        }
    }

    loading.value = false
}

async function getModel(selectedModel: unknown) {
    if (props.fetchModel && isRoutable(selectedModel, props.table)) {
        const json = await useProcessModel(
            // @ts-expect-error
            props.customRouteGroup ?? props.table,
            'show',
            selectedModel,
            {},
        )

        if (json) {
            model.value = json as Record<string, unknown>

            emits('fetchModel', model.value)
        }
    }
}

watch(
    () => props.url,
    async (url, oldUrl) => {
        if (url !== oldUrl) {
            await fetchOptions()

            model.value = {}
        }
    },
)

onBeforeMount(fetchOptions)
</script>

<template>
    <VAutocomplete
        v-model="model"
        :item-title="optionsLabel"
        :item-value="optionsValue"
        :items="items"
        label="Selectați"
        :loading="loading"
        return-object
        @click:clear="model = {}"
        @update:model-value="(model) => getModel(model)"
    >
        <template #append>
            <VBtn
                v-if="!loading"
                :icon="mdiRefresh"
                size="small"
                @click="() => fetchOptions(true)"
                @click.stop
            />
        </template>

        <template v-for="(_, slot) in slots" #[slot]="scope">
            <slot
                :name="slot"
                v-bind="
                    (scope as App.Components.Helpers.UnionToIntersection<
                        typeof scope
                    > as any) || {}
                "
            />
        </template>
    </VAutocomplete>
</template>

